# glossaries-extra.sty

Tags: journal-publishing, glossaries-extra

I am trying to upload a manuscript to a journal system (manuscriptcentral.com) that requires me to upload separately the `main.tex` and all its dependencies. Their system compiles the files into a PDF. I am using the `glossaries-extra` package but the journal's system gives me the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `glossaries-extra.sty' not found.
```

I tried uploading `glossaries-extra.ins` and `glossaries-extra.dtx` but that does not work.

In my `Main.tex` the preamble includes the lines:

```
\usepackage[sort=none]{glossaries-extra}
\input{GDPRglossary.tex}
```

And at the end, I add the glossary:

```
\printunsrtglossary[title={Appendix: Glossary of GDPR terms and their definition}]
```

When I compile on Overleaf it all works fine!

Is there any way to extract `glossaries-extra.sty`? Or is there another workaround?
Thanks!

Comment: Possibly it will work if you upload `glossaries-extra.sty` to the system. This file is present on your system when you install LaTeX and the glossaries-extra package locally. However, from your question I guess that you do not have a local installation and you do everything in Overleaf, which complicates the problem considerably. One solution is to do a local installation (i.e., MikTeX on Windows or TeX Live on Linux or MacTeX on mac) with the added benefit that you are in full control of the system yourself and do not depend anymore on what Overleaf provides.

Comment: Another solution may be to contact Overleaf and ask if they allow to compile `ins` files. A third option may be to find somebody with a local installation and get the file from them, in which case you should check if the package version is (approximately) the same.

Comment: If you have the ins and the dtx you can create the sty: put both in some temp folder and them simply compile the ins with pdflatex.

Comment: Thank you Marjin and Ulrike. You are correct that I don't have a local installation and was hoping to get the sty file without doing so... I will try to email Overleaf

Comment: The `glossaries-extra` package is also distributed as a TDS archive [`glossaries-extra.tds.zip`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra.tds.zip). This contains all the files extracted from the `.dtx` and `.ins` file, but since `glossaries-extra` is in both TeX Live and MikTeX, the error may be an indication that the journal has an old TeX distribution (or not the full installation) so there may be other dependencies missing.

Comment: Thank you @NicolaTalbot! I asked the journal and they will ask the publisher to update the TeX distribution. (I still have not received an answer from Overleaf)